IOS Swift application Intune SDK Socket timeout
I have an IOS application with Intune SDK libraries integrated for MAM (IntuneMAMSwift.xcframework and IntuneMAMSwiftStub.xcframework). However, while running the application, we are receiving the following error in the logs:
nw_socket_connect [C3:2] connectx(18 (guarded), [srcif=0, srcaddr=<NULL>, dstaddr=127.0.0.1:22], SAE_ASSOCID_ANY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, SAE_CONNID_ANY) failed: [1: Operation not permitted]
nw_socket_connect [C3:2] connectx failed (fd 18) [1: Operation not permitted]
nw_socket_connect connectx failed [1: Operation not permitted]

Could you please help resolve this issue, as we aren't triggering these transactions explicitly?
